# exporting MS word documents problem using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-word, xampp

**Everything works fine in local server(xampp) but doesn't work properly in live server.**
I tried to export word file but failed to get expected format output. The first screen shot is in correct format but image is missing in second screen shot which is not expected. The image and also text are retrieved from database(I included all details code below for better understanding).
What are the reasons behind this problem?
[Correct/expected format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9BFG.png)
[wrong/unexpected format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HylDy.png)
controller code

```
public function daily_newspaper_report()
    {
        $todayDate = '';
        $startDate = $this->input->post('startDate');
        $endDate = $this->input->post('endDate');
        $response['data'] = $this->project_model->daily_newspaper_get($startDate, $endDate);
        if ($startDate == $endDate) {
            $todayDate = date_format(date_create($startDate), "d F Y");
        } else {
            $todayDate = date_format(date_create($startDate), "d F Y") . ' to ' . date_format(date_create($endDate), "d F Y");
        }
        $search_array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", ":", ",", "to");
        $replace_array = array("১", "২", "৩", "৪", "৫", "৬", "৭", "৮", "৯", "০", "জানুয়ারী", "ফেব্রুয়ারী", "মার্চ", "এপ্রিল", "মে", "জুন", "জুলাই", "আগষ্ট", "সেপ্টেম্বার", "অক্টোবার", "নভেম্বার", "ডিসেম্বার", ":", ",", "থেকে");
        $response['publish_date'] = str_replace($search_array, $replace_array, $todayDate);
        $this->load->view('sadmin/daily_newspaper_report', $response);
        header("Content-Type: application/msword");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"Articles on Agriculture & Allied Science_" . date_format(date_create($startDate), "d-M-Y") . " to " . date_format(date_create($endDate), "d-M-Y") . ".doc\"");
    }
```

model code

```
    public function daily_newspaper_get($startDate, $endDate)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT documents.*, newspaper.newspaper_name AS 'newspaper', newspaper.logo FROM documents JOIN newspaper WHERE documents.newspaper_name=newspaper.id AND publish_date >= '$startDate' AND publish_date <= '$endDate' AND type_id = 7";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

view code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Daily Newspaper Report</title>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


</head>

<body style="font-size: 18.7px;">

    <?php
    // Page Number EN - BN
    function Bengali_DTN($page_no)
    {
        $englDTN = array(
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", ":", ",", "to"
        );
        $bangDTN = array(
            "১", "২", "৩", "৪", "৫", "৬", "৭", "৮", "৯", "০", "জানুয়ারী", "ফেব্রুয়ারী", "মার্চ", "এপ্রিল", "মে", "জুন", "জুলাই", "আগষ্ট", "সেপ্টেম্বার", "অক্টোবার", "নভেম্বার", "ডিসেম্বার", ":", ",", "থেকে"
        );
        $converted = str_replace($englDTN, $bangDTN, $page_no);
        return $converted;
    }

    // echo base_url();
    foreach ($data as $singleData) { ?>


        <h1 style="text-align: center"> <img height="50" width="150" src="<?php echo base_url() . $singleData->logo; ?>"></h1>
        <h4 style="text-align: center"><?php echo Bengali_DTN(date_format(date_create($singleData->publish_date), "d F Y")); ?>, পৃষ্ঠা-<?php $page_no = $singleData->accession_num;
                                                                            echo Bengali_DTN($page_no); ?></h4>
        <h1><b><?php echo $singleData->title; ?></b></h1>

        <?php
        if ($this->project_model->newspaper_image_get($singleData->id)) {
            $variable = $this->project_model->newspaper_image_get($singleData->id);
        ?>

            <?php
            foreach ($variable as $value) { ?>
                <img width="300" height="200" src="<?php echo base_url() . $value->imagePath; ?>" alt="">
            <?php }
        }
        if (stristr($singleData->article_details, '<img src=')) { ?>
            <div><?php echo str_replace('<img src=', '<img width="300" height="200" src=', $singleData->article_details); ?></div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div><?php echo $singleData->article_details; ?></div>
    <?php }
    }
    ?>

    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Designed and Developed by <span style="font-weight: bold;">Computer & GIS Unit</span></h3>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You mentioned your logo is coming from the database, but not how it is stored there.  As a URL path? As BLOB data? If it's a URL path, I would make sure that the live server has access to the location.

Comment: URL is combined with text which is stored in database as long text.

Comment: Image data is binary data, not text, so if you're storing it as LONGTEXT then I could see you having problems. Unless I misunderstood your comment, and you're storing the text of the document in LONGTEXT, and the image is stored separately in a file directory? If that's the case, then I would reiterate - check that the server has access to the file.